# Problem with skeleton

Tags: armature, pose-mode

So I downloaded model from models-resource.com and after I created some simple skeleton I noticed that few parts of the model are not moving with it. I searched almost everywhere but I couldnt find how to fix this.

[image: The floating parts should be moving with the model but they are not.]

Here is link to download the model: https://www.models-resource.com/pc_computer/schoolofdragons/model/9741/ or you can download it with attached armature:
[image]

Comment: If it's not moving after you've parented to an armature you should share the object with the armature, use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I uploaded it so you can download it

Comment: You need to share the link it has created  ;)

Comment: Im sorry I forgot about that, here it is: https://blend-exchange.com/b/O8nrDgvM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Armature* modifier, enable the 2 first display options, move the bones and select the meshes that don't follow:

[image]

Then assign them to the vertex group they should be part of (the head bone is called *Bone.013* so you need to assign to the vertex group of the same name):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much I spent hours triing fix this bug.